# IEnumerable.MoveNext() returns True but IEnumerable.Current raises a System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, ienumerable, ienumerator, manatee.trello

I am building a C# application using the Manatee.Trello package to handle Trello's API.

I am currently trying to get the first result returned by the Search function. The `Search.Boards` element implements the `IEnumerable<Board>` interface.

This is what I currently have:

```
Search mySearch = new Search(SearchFor.IsOpen(), 100, SearchModelType.Boards);
foreach (Board b in mySearch.Boards) {
      Console.WriteLine("Board Name:{0} _ ID:{1}", b.Name, b.Id);
}
mySearch.Boards.GetEnumerator().Reset();
bool next=mySearch.Boards.GetEnumerator().MoveNext();
Console.WriteLine("MoveNext:{0}", next);
Console.WriteLine("\nBoard Name:{0}", mySearch.Boards.GetEnumerator().Current.ToString());
```

The first foreach loop works fine and displays all the boards my user has access to. `Console.WriteLine("MoveNext:{0}", next)` works as well and displays `MoveNext:True`. However, the last line returns a `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

What is wrong with my code? I know `mysearch` contains data (I tried copying the `foreach` loop just after the `MoveNext()` call, and it works fine). Is there a simpler method to access a specific element of my search result ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GetEnumerator()` returns a **new** enumerator each call. Whatever you think you are doing with the calls to it, you aren't doing it. The result is lost after each line because you don't keep the enumerator variable.

Generally speaking, C# is a high level language. Try to not go down to the depths of manual loop handling. Your `foreach` is just fine.

To access members of an enumeration outside of a foreach loop, LinQ is the easiest way:

```
var board = mySearch.Boards.FirstOrDefault(board => board.Name == "WhatImLookingFor");
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. However, how can I get a specific element of my enumerator without using a foreach loop ?

Comment: @Aserre I added a LinQ example.